# How to remove MPAVController console logs from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, console, mpmovieplayercontroller

Since I last updated XCode I'm getting a lot of MPAVController logs when I play video, like this:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
...
```

It's pretty annoying and fills up the console. How can I turn these off?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804425/turn-off-console-logging-for-specific-objects  which has a couple of interesting solutions (not simple unfortunately).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think those only appear in a debug build. Try using a release build and see if they're gone.

Comment: That kind of misses the point of the entries being annoying when I am debugging :-)

Answer (score -1):

I am using only local video files and after adding this, the log is no longer spammed:

```
MPMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
```

edit: 
It seemed this was the solution in my case, but later I found the logging had returned...